# Replace JSP with Thymeleaf in Legacy Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, thymeleaf

My company wants to level up by deploying our web-application as spring boot executable jar:

### Specifications (Legacy Webpap):

- classic web app (25 years old) but now with Spring
- Over 100 jsp files
- And more jsp files generated by our custom jsp generator
- Custom jsp tag lib with more than 30 java classes

All jsp files are html 4 files with Active X components.

### Problem

One of the main problems is that jsp rendition is not supported in executable jars. Therefore I consider using Thymeleaf. My best guess is to replace the rendition process in our custom jsp generator. In the future (don't know when that is) we plan to migrate to a single page web app but for now I need to run the web app as jar and with our existing templates and tag library.

[Draft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AexAO.png)

### My Question

Is it possible to use Thymeleaf along with our custom tag library?

Comment: Thanks, I removed my unspecific questions.

Comment: Does this workaround would be helpful: [How can I use a custom tag library with Thymeleaf and Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46931461/how-can-i-use-a-custom-tag-library-with-thymeleaf-and-spring-boot)